# How to overload a type definiton of a function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a class structure that exposes a number of user "actions" off the do property:

```js
const instance = new Forest({
value: {x, y},
 actions: {offsetX(f: forest, x: number) { f.do.set_x(f.value.x + x); 
});
```

the Forest instantiates the type leafI

```js
export type leafFn = (...rest: any[]) => any;  // what is exposed on the "do" property
export type leafDoFn = (leaf: leafI, ...rest: any[]) => any; // what gets passed into the

export type leafDoObj = { [name: string]: leafDoFn };
export type leafFnObj = Record<string, leafFn>

export type leafI = {
 ....

  do: leafFnObj;
  value: any;
}
```

what I would like to do is to be able to extend the definition of the
instances a la

```
const instance = new Forest({
value: {x, y},
 actions: {offsetX(f: forest, x: number) { f.do.set_x(f.value.x + x); 
}) as leafI & {
do: {
  offsetX: (x: number, y: number) => void,
} // first parameter is injected internally
```

but typescript won't let me redefine the parameters because they are "defined" (if abstractly) in the leafFn definition.

How can I overload the generic definitions of do exposed methods to be more specific for certain instances?

Comment: What even is your Forest class? We need a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://github.com/bingomanatee/forest-2